# Add mean to grouped box plot in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, boxplot

I created a grouped box plot in R with ggplot2. However, when I want to add the mean, the dots appear between the two boxes in a group. How can I change it such that the dots are within each box?

Here my code:

```
ggplot(results, aes(x=treatment, y=effect, fill=sex)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=20, size=3, color="red")`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `position_dodge2`. Because points and boxplots have differing widths, you will need to trial and error with the `width` argument to centralise the dots.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=hp, fill=factor(vs))) +
geom_boxplot() +
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=20, size=3, color="red",
             position = position_dodge2(width = 0.75,   
                                        preserve = "single"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you will not be able to place the points inside each grouped box as they overlap with each other through the axes. One alternative is to use `facet_wrap`.

Here is one example with `iris` data:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Species), shape = 20, size = 3) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.8) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

If you don't want the color of the points to be the same as the color of the boxplots, you have to remove the grouping variable from the `aes` inside the `geom_point`. Again, with the `iris` example,

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_point(shape = 20, size = 3, color = 'red') +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

Note that the `ggplot2` package works in layers. Therefore, if you add the `geom_point` layer after the `geom_boxplot` layer, the points will be on the top of the boxplot. If you add the `geom_point` layer before the `geom_boxplot` layer, the points will be in the background.

Edit:
If what you want is to add a single point in your boxplot to indicate the mean, you can do something like:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(mean.y = mean(Sepal.Width),
         mean.x = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean.y, x = mean.x), shape = 20, size = 3, color = 'red')
```

But be aware that it would probably require some calibration on the `x` axis to make it exactly in the middle of each box.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can link the mean value to the respective boxplot with similar colors (you had just to add the mapping to the stat_summary function proposed in the first answer)

```
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=hp, color=factor(vs))) + geom_boxplot() + 
stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point",shape=20,size=3,mapping=aes(color=factor(vs)),
             position = position_dodge2(width = 0.75, preserve = "single"))
```

[image]